# Child - parent contraints in MYsql?

Tags: mysql, database, constraints

Can I have them?

I have a constraint that forces delete of the row if a related row from a different table is deleted:

```
node INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,     
title VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
description MEDIUMTEXT,
category VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
parent INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0,             # here is the parent term id
                                           # if it's 0 the term has no parent

PRIMARY KEY(id),
UNIQUE KEY(name, node, category),
KEY parent(parent),
KEY category(category),

CONSTRAINT terms FOREIGN KEY(node)
    REFERENCES nodes(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

I want another constraint that forces auto-delete of the row if the "parent" term is deleted? (if there is a term parent set)

Example:

```
node  |  id  |  name  | title   | description    | category | parent
___________________________________________________________________
534   |    1 |  A     | Foooooo | Bla bla...     | A        | 0 
54    |    2 |  B     | Foooooo | Bla bla...     | A        | 1
45    |    3 |  C     | Foooooo | Bla bla...     | A        | 2
545   |    4 |  D     | Foooooo | Bla bla...     | A        | 2
534   |    5 |  E     | Foooooo | Bla bla...     | A        | 1
```

so terms look like:

```
  A
  - B
  --- C
  --- D
  - E
```

So if I delete B, I want C and D to be deleted as well,
if I delete A, then B, C, D, E should be deleted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "conditional" constraint: Either your parent field **allways** references another row (i.e. no 0 allowed), or it is no constraint at all.

This is quite a normal usecase, typically you would work around it with an `ON DELETE TRIGGER` on the parent, that also deletes the children, selecting them by parent.

In your example you might consider something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER cascade_delete_children 
    BEFORE DELETE ON node 
    FOR EACH ROW 
         DELETE FROM node WHERE parent=OLD.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NULL` instead of `0` and define the `FOREIGN KEY` with cascading deletes:

```
parent INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,    --- here is the parent term id
                                          --- if it's NULL the term has no parent
...

CONSTRAINT parent_fk FOREIGN KEY(parent)
    REFERENCES thisTable(id) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```